# Python: Finding similarity percentage between two images of different angles

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, scikit-image, opencv, python

I am looking for percentage of matching between the two images. Images could be of different pixel size, oriented in different angles or second image could be part of first image.

I have tried difference between pixels, SSIM, SIFT(Brute Force and FANN), SURF, FREAK, BRIEF.

Problem: none of this Models are reaching to the better percentage of matching.
Please find the following sample pictures which using for the comparison

[image: image 1] [image: image 2] [image: image 3]

Please suggest some Good Models for comparison and defining percentage of matching between images.

Let me know if sample code is required will share.

Comment: feature poin methods are not good for very large angle variance cases

Comment: @flankechen Thanks  for your time... Still i am searching( mean time i did with ORB still no hope). Now looking t tensorflow models. I find the link useful but requires rest calls. https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/image-similarity ... Please let me know if any models could give better results

Comment: Try for siamese neural network